# How can I vertically center an icon in an input?

Tags: html, angular-ui-bootstrap

I don't know how to center an icon vertically inside an `input`. This is my code:

```html
<i-feather name="user" class="fea icon-sm icons"></i-feather>
<input type="text" class="form-control ps-5" placeholder="Name" name="s" required="">
```

Currently it looks like this:

[image: HTML input with icon slightly below vertical center]

and I want to achieve an effect like this:

[image: HTML input with icon centered vertically]

How do I center the icon vertically in the `input`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```html
<style>
.input-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.input-wrapper .icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.input-wrapper input {
  padding: 0 0 0 25px;
  height: 50px;
}
</style>

<div class="input-wrapper">
  <i class="icon">2</i>
  <input type="text" class="form-control ps-5" placeholder="Name" name="s" required="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two styling options you can use. These are block and flex.
Block will not be responsive while flex will be responsive. I hope this solve your issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).